# Add Bluetooth to Menu Bar

Tags: bluetooth, panel

I use Bluetooth earbuds, and I want to add Bluetooth settings/configuration to the Menu Bar, like in Windows. How can I do this?

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using Gnome 42.1

Comment: Your question needs clarification. What do you mean by "add Bluetooh"? And "like Windows"? This isn't and never will be anything like Windows (if you want "like Windows" then use Windows!). If what you want is a Bluetooth devices menu in the main menu then there's a GNOME extension for that: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1401/bluetooth-quick-connect/ If other then please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: I want persistent Bluetooth Menu in Gnome Panel like there is available for wifi. I am using Bluetooth quick connet but that also disappear when I turn off Bluetooth. So, I want it to remain like Wifi, remains there even turned off. Like Windows is just a reference @ChanganAuto